# How can I load 'null' from .yml as None (class str), not (class NoneType)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I have yaml that looks like this:

```
  SomeRecord:
    type: array
    items:
      type:
        - string
        - number
        - null
```

I try PyYAML and ruamel.yaml they both convert `'null'` to `None` (class NoneType).
Is there an easy way to change this behavior?

Comment: No. Why would you want to?

Comment: What do you want it to be?  And Why?

Comment: I want to use converted data like json schema to validate answers from server. Python jsonshema module could not validate None as NoneType class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple recursive function to find the `None` values and convert them to `'None'` like this:

#### Code:

```
def convert_none_to_str(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        data[:] = [convert_none_to_str(i) for i in data]
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            data[k] = convert_none_to_str(v)
    return 'None' if data is None else data
```

#### Test Code:

```
yaml_data = """    
  SomeRecord:
    type: array
    items:
      type:
        - string
        - number
        - null
"""

import yaml
data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_data)
print(data)
convert_none_to_str(data)
print(data)
```

#### Results:

```
{'SomeRecord': {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': ['string', 'number', None]}}}
{'SomeRecord': {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': ['string', 'number', 'None']}}}
```